# Loader and onLoadFinished() after orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-loadermanager, android-loader

I init a loader on *Fragment*'s onCreate() like this snippet:

```
if (null == savedInstanceState) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, args, this);
}
```

well, it works and data are normally returned on`onLoadFinished()`. But if I change orientation while loader is yet loading data, then `onLoadFinished()` is never called after. 
Please, can someone explain to me why? Thanks

Comment: why don't you use it in `onActivityCreated` without `if` at all ? ...  initLoader should return cached result after orientation changed

Comment: i will try on `onActivityCreated`, but i think that it should work on `onCreate()` too.

Comment: @Selvin well, i tried without `if` statement: it works, even in onCreate(). The reason, i think, is that _Loader_ needs to be reinitialized each time to return cached data.
Your comment is essentially correct, post it as reply and I will accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `if (null == savedInstanceState)` check - by adding that check, the loader is not moved to the 'started' state when the activity is recreated and only loaders that are started will return results.